# Allocate Predefined Private IPs when launching EC2 using Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a MEAN application where I am using Private IP to provide the connection in between the server or application. And I am using ec2 Instance Private IP for this inside my application.

Now I want to use Auto Scaling for my Production Environment. But I am not able to allocate predefined Private IPs when launching ec2 Instance using Auto Scaling Group.

```
Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps through Launch Configurations?
```

What is the best method to allow ec2 instances launched by an Auto Scaling Group to be assigned a private IP?

Comment: Can you give more information regarding how you are using the IP inside your application? You should be using AWS Security Group membership to open ports instead of specifying private IP addresses, but I'd need more information about what your application is doing to provide a complete alternative approach to using specific IPs.

Comment: Where do you put the IP addresses — in a master server that then talks to a slave machine? What happens when Auto Scaling terminates one of the instances — how does the system react to losing an instance? Please edit your question to provide more information about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to have specific private IP's reserved for the auto scaling group in the launch configurations for **ec2** Instance.

**However three possible workaround here.**

1. As per as **Private IP** is concern kindly create small subnet and choose it when creating **Auto Scaling Group**.
2. Create **ENI (network interface)** and assign it **Private IP** address of your choice, In the **Auto Scaling Launch Configuration** write user data script which uses the **AWS cli tools** to discover the pre created **ENI** and attach it to the **ec2 Instance**.
3. You may also try adding **Secondary Private IP** address to instance primary interface using user data.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling adjusts capacity by:

- Launching new instances
- Terminating existing instances

When a new instance is launched, it receives a private IP address in the CIDR range of the associated subnet. While it is normally possible in Amazon EC2 to request a specific IP address (which is done via a DHCP reservation), this is not possible with Auto Scaling. Instead, each instance will receive a random address from the subnet's CIDR range.

If your application really does require a range of pre-defined IP addresses, you could use a pool of Elastic IP addresses and have each new instance "grab" one of these addresses. However, traffic within a VPC that refers to a public IP address (and an Elastic IP address is a public IP address) has a charge of 1c/GB because it goes out, and then back into, the VPC. I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Given that there could be a variable number of instances operating at any time, and therefore assuming that your application can handle the fact that it might have an IP address registered but not in use, you could just give it every IP address in the CIDR range. You could even make a smaller subnet so the range is not very big.

Comment: One clarification about making smaller subnets: as of today (July 2021) smallest allowed subnets are /28 so if anyone is trying to create, let's say, /31 or /32 it will fail.